# Dieharder weak results even with RA mode

Tags: command-line

I've created a quantum-random number generator as part of my thesis and I'm trying to test it using the Dieharder test suite.

However, I still seem to get a few weak results (not reproducibly on the same test) even though I'm using `-a -y 1 -k 2` as my options.

[The man page indicates that -y should resolve ambiguities to either a pass or a fail, with no weak results.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, the flag to resolve ambiguity is `-Y 1`, not `-y 1`, which passes a parameter to the running test. Judging by that, you probably want `-a -Y 1 -k 2`, not `-y`.

(Disclaimer: I've never used the tool in question, this is just from reading the manual page.)

Comment: That'd be the one... Thanks